# How to group attendance logs of a specific User - Eloquent

Tags: php, eloquent

i'm creating an attendance report module.

i have two tables, one is `User` table and the other one is `attendance_log`

here's the column of each table

`Users` table

`---------------------------------
|user_id | first_name | lastname|
|    1   | jesse      | leech   |
|    2   | howard     | jones   |`

`attendance_log` table

`---------------------------------
|log_id | user_id | status   | created_at          | updated_at          |
|    1  | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:08:57 | 2017-08-09 13:08:57 |
|    2  | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:09:00 | 2017-08-09 13:09:00 |
|    3  | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:09:03 | 2017-08-09 13:09:03 |
|    4  | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:10:28 | 2017-08-09 13:10:28 |
|    5  | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:10:30 | 2017-08-09 13:10:30 |
|    6  | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-09 13:10:31 | 2017-08-09 13:10:31 |
|    7  | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:08:57 | 2017-08-10 13:08:57 |
|    8  | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:09:00 | 2017-08-10 13:09:00 |
|    9  | 1       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:09:03 | 2017-08-10 13:09:03 |
|    10 | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:10:28 | 2017-08-10 13:10:28 |
|    11 | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:10:30 | 2017-08-10 13:10:30 |
|    12 | 2       | entrance | 2017-08-10 13:10:31 | 2017-08-10 13:10:31 |`

as you can see to the `attendance_log` table, i have multiple `created_at` value, because im using rfid tapping for inserting data for the attendance.

here's my problem, when i'm grouping it by `created_at` the result will be:

`-----------------------------------------------
| first name | last name | date & time         |
| jesse      | leech     | 2017-08-09 13:08:57 |
| jesse      | leech     | 2017-08-10 13:08:57 |`

instead of:

`-----------------------------------------------
| first name | last name | date & time         |
| jesse      | leech     | 2017-08-09 13:08:57 |
| jesse      | leech     | 2017-08-10 13:08:57 |
| howard     | jones     | 2017-08-09 13:10:28 |
| howard     | jones     | 2017-08-10 13:10:28 |`

how can i achieve this?

here's my code

```
    $students = User::has('userStudentAttendance')->with(['userStudentAttendance' => function($query) use ($details,$search_from, $search_to){
    $query->where('status', $details);
    $query->where(function($query) use ($search_from, $search_to){
            $query->whereBetween(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'), [$search_from, $search_to]);
        });
    $query->groupby(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'));
    }])
    ->leftjoin('sys_user_student', 'sys_user_student.user_id', '=', 'sys_user.user_id')
    ->leftjoin('sys_mf_section', 'sys_mf_section.section_id', '=', 'sys_user_student.section_id')
    ->leftjoin('sys_mf_grade', 'sys_mf_grade.grade_id', '=', 'sys_mf_section.grade_id')     
    ->where('user_type_id', '4')
    ->where('sys_mf_section.section_id', $request->getParam('section_id'))
    ->where('sys_mf_grade.grade_id', $request->getParam('grade_id'))        
    ->get();
```

hoping someone can help me and sorry for my poor english. Thank you guys!

Comment: In case of experiment because i don't know how does eloquent works: you can group your values by `user_id` also. Something like `$query->groupby('user_id');`

Comment: i've tried it @marv255 , but same result

Comment: Why did you prefer 2017-08-09 13:08:57 for jesse over other values. As i can see other logs for the same date - 2017-08-09 13:09:00 & 2017-08-09 13:09:03 ?